# BULMA: How to get equal width for first column? Only by using a table?

Tags: css, flexbox, grid, multiple-columns, bulma

building a web page using Bulma I want to display several events in this way:

```
<div class="card" style="background: lightgreen;">
    <div class="card-header p-4">
      <div class="is-flex is-flex-direction-row ">
        <div class="has-text-right pr-4 is-one-quarter" style="white-space: nowrap;">
          <strong>[1st column]</strong><br/>
```

See https://codepen.io/baschtl/pen/PobXamm

[image: Screenshot]

But I want to have the first column for each "row/line" always have the equal width.

But maybe this would be only possible by using the good, old TABLE element [https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/table/] and not columns or something else, too?

**Thanks a lot!**

mtemp

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the width of the first column with is-x class which can be is-1 to is-12.

```
<div class="columns">
    <div class="column is-1"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this framework but this is pretty simple to do in CSS.
You could add a class with width to each first element like this

```
.width-fix{
  width:10rem;
}
```

Your html (minus white-space:nowrap and added width-fix class):

```
<div class="card" style="background: lightgreen;">
    <div class="card-header p-4">
      <div class="is-flex is-flex-direction-row ">
        <div class="width-fix has-text-right pr-4 is-one-quarter">
          <strong>[1st column]</strong><br/>
          Saturday<br /><strong>27th May 2022</strong> 
        </div>

        <div class="pr-4" style="min-width: 80px;">
          <strong>[2nd column]</strong><br/>
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <figure class="image is-128x128">
              <img class="is-rounded" src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/128x128.png">
            </figure>
          </a>
</div>
```

Also keep in mind that using table isn't bad if you actually need a table, so you could also consider that.